# How to Stop & Start Screen Jobs Using Scripts in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, gnu-screen

I want to use some scripts to stop and start a bunch of programs, each running in a separate linux screen. These programs run continuously and need to be stopped using Ctrl-C.
So I can write some code to stop a screen:

```
screen -S "mysessionname" -X quit
```

but do I need to send a Ctrl-C somehow first of all and if so then how?

Also, I can start a new detached screen thus from within a script:

```
screen -mdS "mysesssionname"
```

but how can I then kick of the job from within this screen using a script? I've tried attaching to the session and then starting the job all from within a script but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Well let's hope that this can help you but to simulate the Ctrl-C in a script as far as i know you can use something like kill -3 and the pid of the process. See in manual of signals: "man 7 signal"